# Converting UML State Machine to SCL?

Tags: uml, enterprise-architect, state-machine, plc

I would like to know if I can program a PLC with a state machine/diagram.

With the help of Sparx EA we can compose our state machine. Is there any chance to convert this state machine into SCL(Structured Control Language, used in PLC-Programming)? Or what kind of data can we take from the Sparx EA, that we can use as input for the PLC-Programming?

Or maybe you have a better idea how to realize this idea.

Answer (score 2):

Sure.  You need a code generator tool that can read the state machine diagram, and generate equivalent Structured Text.

The shape of the code is pretty straightforward.  You can define a ST boolean for each bit (if you can have live parallel states as in StateCharts) or an ST integer containing a state number.

The ST code for each state is then:

```
   if (StateXXX) then
       <action in this state>
       if (somecondition)
          StateXXX=false;
          StateYYY=true;
       endif
   endif
```

You need to generate this code for each state.

That leaves the question of what *tool* do you use to accomplish this?
Arguably any tool that can read the UML diagram, which is generally exportable as an XML document from UML editors; with the parsed XML, you can write code to climb over it and spit out the above code fragments.

This is perhaps easier if you code fragments which are well defined templates.  You can use ad hoc templates (simply text strings containing markers where something has to be filled in) or you can use a tool that enforces the structure and composition of generated code, such as a [Program Transformation System (PTS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_transformation).

A PTS accepts the grammar for a language, will parse instances of that language, and let you transform that language, finally spitting out the modified language instance.  A useful special case is transforming, if you like, the trivial program into a complex, real program.  In addition, a good PTS will let you write patterns and transformation rules in terms of formal code templates,that enforce at least the syntax of the template to be valid.  This ensures that the pieces you work with always make a certain minimum amount of sense.  (In contrast, you can write any garbage you like in a text template).  When you write lots of such patterns, this is pretty helpful to avoid producing junk.

For this particular example, for (my company's PTS called DMS, see bio) you can write patterns for the above fragment:

```
 pattern StateInstance(statenumber: natural, action: statements, exit_condition: expression, exit_state: natural): statement =
   " if (StateNumber=\statenumber) then
        \action
        if (\exit_condition) then
          StateNumber=\exit_state
        endif
      endif
    ";
```

DMS provides APIs to instantiate this pattern (and others, you typically write many) and compose their results (using instantiated patterns as arguments to other patterns to instantiate) to produce the final program.  You can also add transformation rule to optimize the generated code.  (DMS is driven by grammar definitions; it already knows 40+ languages and in particular has robust definitions for ST and for XML).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But in building the s7 code, I can't place the whole code in one document. So in s7, we have to place it in different modules. That means that I also have to automate the proccess to make new module and copy some codes into it. Any idea?

Comment: That's just more transformations.  A PTS should be able to manufacture multiple source files from a single input document.  The module structure itself is just another pattern to be filled in with part of the code.  You'll need some extra machinery in the PTS to decide which part of the overall generated code goes in which file.   Most PTSs can do analysis but sometimes it is awkward; DMS has lots of support for custom analyzers.   What's the criteria?

Answer (score 1):

I never really have programmed S7 but basically know what you are looking for. EA does not have a generator for SCL and chances are low to see that coming from Sparx. So there are two possibilities.

First (but not preferred by me) is to delve into the guts of the Sparx macro language which is used during code generation. If you just need minor adaptation for existing templates that's fine, but writing a complete new one is no fun (for me).

The second way is to use the API for code generation. This is fairly easy (well, for me since I studied compiler construction at university). What you would do is to take the state machine, traverse it and spit out the according language constructs. It heavily depends on your skills, but I'd create a rough prototype in a couple of days.

**Edit** Here is a sample Perl (I know it's a PITA if you don't use it for a week or so, but you can likely decipher it though) script that parses a state machine using EA's API:

```
package Compiler;
use strict;
use Win32::OLE qw (in);

sub new {
  my ($self, $rep) = @_;
  $self = {};
  $self->{nodes} = {};
  $self->{rep} = $rep;
  bless $self;
}

sub traverse {
  my ($self, $node) = @_;
  my $guid = $node->ElementGUID;
  return if defined($self->{nodes}->{$guid});
  my $nodeInfo = { 'name' => $node->Name, 'type'=> $node->Type, 'out' => ()};
  $self->{nodes}->{$guid} = $nodeInfo;

  for my $trans (in $node->Connectors) {
    my $target = $self->{rep}->GetElementByID($trans->SupplierID);
    next if $target->ElementGUID eq $guid;

    my @targetInfo = ($trans->TransitionGuard, $target->ElementGUID);
    push(@{$nodeInfo->{out}}, \@targetInfo);
    $self->traverse($target);
  }
}

1;
```

and a simple main program like this:

```
use strict;
no strict 'refs';
use compiler;

my $rep = $ENV{'REP'}; # get repository pointer "by magic"
my $node = $rep->GetElementByGUID('{574C5E0C-E032-44c6-A6B0-783D35B9958B}'); # fixed addressing of InitialNode
my $compiler = Compiler->new($rep); 
$compiler->traverse($node); # read in all possible transitions/states
my %states = %{$compiler->{nodes}}; # this hash holds all states and their transitions

for my $key (keys %states) {
  my $state = $states{$key}; # loop through all found states
  print "$state->{type} $state->{name}\n"; # state name
  for my $out (@{$state->{out}}) {
    my ($guard, $guid) = @{$out};
    my $target = $compiler->{nodes}->{$guid};
    print "__$guard -> $target->{name}\n";
  }
}
```

Now assume you have a state machine like this:

[image]

When you run the above program it will print

> StateNode  
>   StateNode  
>   __no condition -> State1 
>   State State1 
>   __condition -> State2 
>   __exit ->  
>   State State2 
>     other condition -> State1

The first StateNode is the unnamed exit and the next the InitialNode (you could also get that info from the API and use it). `State1` has two possible transitions (to exit and `State2`). And `State2` only transits to `State1`.

Now, with the list of named states you can create some enumeration for your different states. Also you have the guards for all transitions which you can transform into if-cascades or switch-statements.

Of course this is not a complete code generator, but you can get the idea how to make one from this scaffold.

Comment: Well I am an automation student, 3rd Semester. That will be really nice if I can see your prototype. :)

Comment: That would for sure be too long as an answer here. Basically, take the StartNode, get the outgoing Transitions, evaluate the guards and create states for all the States you reach.

Comment: I can give my email address if you really want to send me your prototype. I see that you know this theme well, how long will it be, to produce the "code translator" and can you say the qualification that the programmer should have?. Because I would like to know if it will be a right move to use state machine rather than SCL. So at the and the user should just make the state machine, and it will be easier for the people in marketing and bussiness division

Comment: Let me see if I can hack a scaffold these days. Depends on my time available for it.

Comment: Regardless of which engine you use to do code generation, the state machine specification is always going to be nicer than ST code, because the state machine makes the states *obvious*, and the ST code ends up disguising it. (An alternative for most industrial controllers is to use Sequential Function Charts, which can easily encode state machines directly).

Comment: I added an example how to use the API to get you going with a code generator.

Comment: @IraBaxter sequential function charts is also an option, since the s7 accepts the S7-Graph, which looks like the Sequential Function Charts

Comment: Thank you so much, your answer has given me a start point. Last question : you made the state machine using sparx ea? or using something else?

Comment: @ThomasKilian umm I visited the websie from sparx just now and it can translate directly to c++ and several other languages. FYI. Thanks again for your code

Comment: This was made with EA since you were talking about EA in your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Siemens PLC-s then S7 had optional software package called s7-graph: http://w3.siemens.com/mcms/simatic-controller-software/en/step7/simatic-s7-graph/Pages/Default.aspx. You can implement state machines there. But don't know of any importing options for it.

I used it for some equipment that were controlled as state machines. That software package was not free, i don't remember it's price. I also don't know if all S7 PLC families supported it. I used 400 series and it worked there.

Ask your local Siemens distributor to let you play with it a bit before using it in any project.

Answer (score -1):

i have write a template in EA to realize the code generation PLCopen Code from class diagramms, state machine into ST/SCL code (IEC61131 in Twincat/Codesys).

Class diagramm is used to describe the structure for the programm like FB, DUT.
State machine is used to describe the dynamic process for the plc programm.
So that a whole oop plc programm (with Interface, inherit) will be automatic from UML modell generated.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z071cZgMbZ8

Here i have create a new toolbox, which is specific for the modeling for plc programm in EA

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RfDxkq_hDvw&t=2s